# Why call Object.create inside an array.push returns a list of empty objects?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I need to create an array of objects which value of the properties is set dinamically based on an existent array of objects that contains server response.

The flow in this code seems correct to me (also according to some articles on the web) but all I receive as result is an array of n empty objects (neither id: null is displayed).

```
infoForecasts = [];

buildWidget() {
    this.listForecasts.map( (i) => {
        const ser = this.utilitiesService;
        return this.infoForecasts.push(
            Object.create(
                {
                    id: null,
                    time: ser.getCurrTime(ser.getDateTime(i.dt))
                }
            )
        );
    });
}
```

I also tried to:

```
...

time: Object.values(ser.getCurrTime(ser.getDateTime(i.dt))
```

but anything changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read how to use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Using_propertiesObject_argument_with_Object.create()).

Comment: Not sure why `Object.create` is not working here. However, why not use `.push({ id: null, time: <you time>})` here?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I tried that before and it works, but then deleted it because I thought that was some kind of bad practice. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NadynG that's not a bad practice at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

It should not be use to loop an array, use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead.

What i suggest you to do is using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this :

```
this.listForecasts.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => [
    ...acc,
    {
      id: null,
      time: this.utilitiesService.getCurrTime(
        this.utilitiesService.getDateTime(cur.dt)
      )
    }
  ],
  []
);
```

however if you're only trying to push something then `Array.push({ id: '', time: '' })` should be perfectly fine !

Comment: That works and it is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: What benefit does reduce() have over map() in this instance?

Comment: reduce() is built on top of a map() method, you could do the same with map, if this is what you ask

Comment: However if you ask why reduce(), then because it allow to transform an input to anything (array, object ...) without to many syntax

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Fabien. 

So your argument would be - You may not want to return a value for every element of the listForecasts or you may want to return some other collection (like a Map/Set/...) so one might as well use reduce() as a sort of future-proofing?

I guess it then comes down to how you like to write code and whether you want to add the scope for this functionality at the start or add it later as the need arises.

Comment: Exactly, in the end its all about opinion